# How to add a collection-bound select box to a form in Backbone.Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a member form in which there is a select box for choosing a group of this member.

I'm using Backbone & Backbone.Marionette. The member form is bound to a MemberModel. Data for the select box comes from a GroupCollection. MemberModel contains only a group_id, not any reference to a GroupCollection.

I'm now generating this select box manually (fetch GroupCollection then add  to select box by using Javascript).

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it in Backbone.Marionette. I thought it could be done with ListView and ItemView but I couldn't know how to add the select box to this Member form because this form is not a Layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's many different ways that this could be done, and a CollectionView could be used. You would have to set the CollectionView's `tagName` to "select" and then the itemView used with the CollectionView would have a tagName set to "option".

The easier idea might be to use an ItemView on it's own, with your collection as the data source. You can use a collection with an ItemView no problem, you just have to do the loop in your template.

Using underscore.js templates:

```
<script type='text/template' id='some-template'>
  <select>
    <%= _.each(items, function(item){ %>
    <option value="<%= item.value %>"><%= item.name %>
    <%= }) %>
  </select>
</script>
```

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#some-template"
  // ...
})
```

I wrote about these two basic options in more detail, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Derick. I rewrote my template code as your suggestion (not in Underscore but in Handlebars). I don't no longer pass directly a MemberModel to the View, but I create a ViewModel before. Something like that: var viewModel = new Backbone.Model(); viewModel.set({member: member, groups: groups}); The template then can read from viewModel.groups and render as expected.

Comment: Derick your link is not working anymore. I tried the approach with using the itemview but the view is not rendered when the collection is done with the fetch operation. Shouldn't this be done automatically?